# React Native app is crashing in app release apk

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any way to monitor or detect what's causing the crash at launch screen? There was no issue on the development mode but it cannot be started after installing the APK. My app is running on `react-native: 0.65.1`

My android/build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
```

I'm using this command to generate APK `gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Comment: You could integrate some library to monitor your crash, an example would be RNFirebase. Make use of the `log` feature, check out [their document](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/crashlytics#log).

Comment: sentry is your friend.